# How to use testcafe for client side performance testing?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to use testcafe for client side performace testing.Is it possible or is their any alternate option is available for client side performance testing?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe is intended for the e2e testing, not for the load/performance testing.

However, you can use approaches described in this thread:

[Testcafe concurrent load test performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731078/testcafe-concurrent-load-test-performance).